# Is Big Omega of any linear algorithm n or can it also be 1?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

If we have a linear algorithm (for example, find if a number exists in a given array of numbers), does this mean that `Omega(n) = n`? The number of steps would be `n`. And the tightest bound I can make is `c*n` where `c = 1`.

But as far as I know, Omega also describes the best case scenario which in this case would be **1** because the searched element can be on the first position of the array and that accounts for only one step. So, by this logic, `Omega(n) = 1`.

Which variant is the correct one and why? Thanks.

Comment: There is the concept of best case, worst case and average case. Also notice that an algorithm running on n elements can have a worst case lower than n (log n in your example if the list is sorted)

Comment: Big O notation (AKA algorithm complexity) doesn't describe the best case. For a linear algorithm, therefore, the complexity is O(n).

Comment: Big-O describes an upper bound. A linear algorithm is also in `O(n^5)`. It's an upper bound, but not the best. Big-Omega describes a lower bound. Combining both gives you Theta, the *real complexity class*. None of them have to do with best or worst cases. All of them are always tied to the worst case of the scenario to analyze (because of the *for all* in the definition). If you want to analyze a specific case you need to explicitly restrict the input domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a large confusion about what is described using the asymptotic notation.

The running time of an algorithm is in general a function of the number of elements, but also of the particular values of the inputs. Hence `T(x)` where `x` is an input of `n` elements is not a function of `n` alone.

Now one can study the worst-case and best-case: to determine these, you choose a configuration of the input corresponding to the slowest or fastest execution time and these are functions of `n` only. And additional option is the expected (or average) running-time, which corresponds to a given statistical distribution of the input. This is also a function of `n` alone.

Now, `Tworst(n)`, `Tbest(n)`, `Texpected(n)` can have upper bounds, denoted by `O(f(n))`, and lower bounds, denoted by `Ω(f(n))`. When these bounds coincide, the notation `Θ(f(n))` is used.

In the case of a linear search, the best case is `Θ(1)` and the worst and expected cases are `Θ(n)`. Hence the running time for arbitrary input is `Ω(1)`
 and `O(n)`.

---

**Addendum:**

The Graal of algorithmics is the discovery of efficient algorithms, i.e. such that the effective running time is of the same order as the best behavior that can be achieved *independently of any algorithm*.

For instance, it is obvious that the worst-case of any search algorithm is `Ω(n)` because whatever the search order, you may have to perform `n` comparisons (for instance if the key is not there). As the linear search is worst-case `O(n)`, it is worst-case efficient. It is also best-case efficient, but this is not so interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an linear time algorithm that means that the time complexity has a linear **upper** bound, namely `O(n)`. This does not mean that it also has a linear lower bound. In your example, finding out if a element exits, the lower bound is `Ω(1)`. Here is `Ω(n)` just wrong.

Doing a linear search on an array, to find the minimal element takes exactly `n` steps in all cases. So here is the lower bound `Ω(n)`. But `Ω(1)` would also be right, since a constant number of steps is also a lower bound for `n` steps, but it is no tight lower bound.